# How to Setup a Full Node on Azure?

Tags: iri-node, iota-network

I have spare credits for Azure, I'd love to use this to setup a full node for IOTA. I know there are Amazon AWS guides, just wondered if anyone had an easy way to do this for Azure?

Comment: I doubt there is a guide for Azure already and probably not much knowledge about Azure here either. So why don't you give it a try and write something up afterwards?

Comment: Okay geat!, But, this has been a few years now. are they also setting up this as an integrated app in Azure? More like a click an play setup?

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend this tutorial: http://iota.partners/
The setup is everytime the same. You just need to create a VM with SSH access.

For more automatic setup the following scripts can be used:

- Setup with Docker: https://github.com/ixidion/iota-docker
- Setup without Docker: https://github.com/nuriel77/iri-playbook

Comment: Just for completeness - don't forget to set the right ports in the network setup of the VM network to enable external connections to your node.